# Работа с реестром на Qt

Tags: c++, qt5

Используется Qt 5.6.1 C++
Вообще, мне надо изменять существующее значение параметра, перед этим его проверив.
Но сначала я решил просто попробовать создать параметр со значением.
После долгого изучения классов Qt написал такой код:

```
QSettings checkinst("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\MYPROGRAMM", QSettings::NativeFormat);
checkinst.setValue("JustUpdated", 20);
```

Программа компилируется без ошибок. Путь, написанный в первой строке, существует, такого параметра там до запуска программы нет. Затем я запускаю программу, данный код выполняется. Однако, в реестре данный параметр не появляется. Почему? Что я делаю не так?

Upd.
Я прочитал параметр и вывел на экран, вывелось значение, которое я задал, однако в реестре я его не наблюдаю. Похоже, что-то с адресом не так, не могу понять, что...

Upd2.
Додумался сделать поиск по реестру того параметра, который я создаю. Он нашелся! Но совсем по непонятному пути:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VirtualStore\Machine\Software\Wow6432Node\Myprogram

Что это за путь такой, откуда он взялся? Я ведь указывал другой путь.

Comment: Попробуй `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\MYPROGRAMM"`

Comment: Попробовал, тоже самое.

Comment: Могу только предположить, что после `setValue`, возможно, нужно как-то закрепить изменения? Есть какой-нибудь `save` или `commit`? `sync()` похож на то, что Вам нужно

Comment: Стоп. Может быть после записи в реестр - нужно обновить просто окошко редактора реестра? И еще вариант - вызвать `void QSettings::sync()` (но это автоматом вызывает деструктор)

Comment: Может быть не `MYPROGRAMM`, а `MYPROGRAM` (с одной `M`)

Comment: предполагаю, что у вас 32 битное приложение на 64 битной системе. Для такого случая параметры реестра находятся в ноде Wow6432Node, ex: HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/MyProgram

Comment: sync эффекта не имел, однако последний комментатор почти попал в суть. Я додумался сделать поиск параметра, который создавала программа, и обнаружил его совсем по другому адресу. Вот бы понять, откуда взялся этот адрес.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://990x.top/virtualstore-chto-eto-za-papka-i-mozhno-li-ee-udalit.html

Вот здесь довольно весело описывается, откуда берется этот путь. При этом если программа будет запущена от имени администратора, путь будет тем, который указан в коде. Чтобы разницы не было, лучше сразу в коде указать путь в этот раздел.

Upd. Выписка с сайта.

Некоторые программы хотят хранить данные свои в таких папках как Program Files, Windows.. Еще они могут захотеть внести данные в системные разделы реестра. Винде это откровенно говоря не нравится и она начинает применять технологию виртуализации (это вроде имеется ввиду UAC, но я могу ошибаться).

Как все работает? Смотрите, прога хочет писать данные например в эту папку:

C:\Windows

Но винда тихонько перенаправит запрос записи вот сюда:

C:\Пользователи\имя_юзера\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows

Понимаете? Прога будет думать что все пучком и она пишет данные в папку Windows, хотя как бэ это так и есть, но сама папка Windows при этом находится в папке VirtualStore..

Тоже самое касается и реестра, если прога например хочет записать данные вот сюда:

HKLM\Software

То винда тихо перенаправит все это дело сюда:

HKLM\Software\Classes\VirtualStore

Comment: Укажите основные тезисы не по ссылке, а в самом ответе. Так, при инвалидации ссылки, ответ не станет бесполезным